# URL rewriting with dynamic parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, parameters, url-rewriting

Is it possible to rewrite URL to form with GET parameters if the count and name of parameters is not set in the first place?

Let's say I have this

```
/categories/key_1/111/    
/categories/key_1/111/key_2/222/
/categories/key_1/333/key_2/444/key_3/555/
/categories/key_5/333/key_6/444/key_7/555/
```

Can I rewrite this to form?

```
/categories/?key_1=111&key_2=222....&key_x=xxx
```

if the order, amount and name of parameters *is not static*

The only condition is that *KEY-VALUE* pair is set like this

/root_folder/**key_x**/**value_x**/

Answer (score 1):

This single recursive should be able to do that:

```
RewriteEngine On

# to convert /categories/n1/v1/n2/v2 to /categories/?n2=v2&n1=v1
RewriteRule ^(categories)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ /$1/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Actually no. I don't know is it tested by you, but I tested it on real server, regexp tester and htaccess online tester
Rewrited url is 
/categories//n2/v2?n1=v1

Comment: There is no redirect in this rule so URL won't change with this rule. It worked pretty well on my Apache. You should provide full htaccess in question, probably there is a conflicting rule.

Comment: Rewriting URL means that url WILL change. It wont change in browser as there is not redirect, but Apache will process rewrited URL, not the one you requested in browser. And no, it's not work. I used blank htaccess. Did you tested in regexp editor? It rewrites the URL in the string I posted above.

Comment: RegExp editor is not the right way to test mod_rewrite rules since `mod_rewrite` runs in a loop. Yes it is working perfectly fine using `http://localhost/categories/key_5/333/key_6/444/key_7/555/` URL on my Apache. So obviously your setup is an issue here not the rules. Does your `categories` directory have an `index.php`?